# Crystal Reports Get value of specified id

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

i got an xml file in crystal report which is build like that:

```
Columns:  ID     value
          1      4
          2      7
          3      99
```

now I want to save the values with the ID of 2 and 3 in a formula for later use.
But how do I do that?

I tried to make create two formulas who look like this:

```
Shared stringVar value1;
if({XMLFile.ID} = 2) then
value1:= {XMLFile.Value}
```

and

```
Shared stringVar value2;
if({XMLFile.ID} = 3) then
value2:= {XMLFile.Value}
```

But if I display them in the "details" area of my report only one number is displayed. There is no selection filter or anything and these values exist.

Comment: You can create two additional formulas, returning just value1 and value2 - and these formulas need to include WhilePrintingRecords(); statement.

Comment: I just did that - it's not working too. The displayed values are both empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work.

I just added the XML file twice. So my formulas look like that

```
Shared stringVar value1;
if({XMLFile.ID} = 2) then
value1:= {XMLFile.Value}
```

and

```
Shared stringVar value2;
if({XMLFile_copy.ID} = 3) then
value2:= {XMLFile_copy.Value}
```